# How to create independent frames?

Tags: html, css, iframe, frame

In my page I have a frame .I need to design the frame independently and just place it in my page.I does not want to specify the frames style in the page where it included.But in the frame's style sheet.

I desinged the frame as follows
http://jsfiddle.net/Hf2pR/

In my page I included the frame as follows

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lckh/

The problem is that the width of the frame is not 20% (I specified 20%).
How to solve this?
How to independently design a frame and use it by just including it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong then you are trying to load the iframe in any page and the height and width of the frame have to be set by the page which is loading into the iframe (not in the parent page where the iframe is). This code has to be inside your script tag in the page you are loading into your iframe. window.parent.window.document.getElementByTagName('iframe')[0].style.width='100px'

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can define your iframe width properties as like this

```
<iframe class ='cLeft' src = './leftPanel.html' FRAMEBORDER="0" SCROLLING="yes" width="20%">
</iframe>
```

Live Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/9Lckh/1/

or This

```
iframe
{
    border:none !important;
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: i need to specify with of iframe in its own  stylesheet..i dont want styles for iframe  in parent page.The frame should be independent